# start a for loop from current position

Tags: vb.net

i have a for loop "for each val in values" I want to within this loop some how check positions ahead of the current position for a condition. I am unsure how i can do this however apart from having an inner for loop to loop from the current position. If that is the case I am not sure how i can get the current position. Can any1 help me out here?

I have attempted this with this code below, the inner for loop.

```
   If creditPoints = "10" Then
            Dim valcount As Integer = Val.Count
            For intLoopIndex = valcount To Values.Count

                If Val.Contains("1-2") And Val.Contains("20") Then

                    isAvailable = False

                End If

            Next
        End If
```

thanks

Comment: Where is `intLoopIndex` used in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow what you are trying to do with your code within the loop, but `intLoopIndex` contains the current value for the current loop.

So, if you want one ahead of the current loop, use `intLoopIndex + 1`.  For one behind, use `intLoopIndex - 1`.

Comment: sorry i want to loop from the current index to the end of the list? how can i do that

Comment: You can have a loop within your loop.  `For innerLoopIndex = intLoopIndex to Values.Count`

Comment: can i get a string value then out of one of these variable? Now that i have the innerLoopIndex?

Comment: Sure.  I don't know what type `Values` is, but for arrays you can do `Values(innerLoopIndex)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `For` instead of a `ForEach` in order to know where you are in the array and use `Linq` to filter the remaining values.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Values As String() = {"1", "1-2", "3", "20", "5"}


    For index As Integer = 0 To Values.Length - 1

        If IsAvailable(Values.Skip(index).ToArray()) Then
            'Do something
            Console.WriteLine("Is available for index={0}", index)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Not available for index={0}", index)
        End If

    Next


End Sub

Public Function IsAvailable(ByVal Values As String()) As Boolean
    Return Values.Any(Function(s) s.Contains("1-2") OrElse s.Contains("20"))
End Function
```

with the output:

```
Is available for index=0
Is available for index=1
Is available for index=2
Is available for index=3
Not available for index=4
```